# can't install smach_viewer on ros melodic

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried installing smach with the command

```
$ sudo apt-get install ros-melodic-smach ros-melodic-smach-ros ros-melodic-
executive-smach ros-melodic-smach-viewer
```

from the book i'm reading ROS Robotics Projects by Ramkumar Gandhinathan, Lentin Joseph. while the other packages got installed the smach_viewer package gave a 404 error. After checking the package on [this link](http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-melodic-smach-viewer/) i found out that some of the deb files were missing. please how do i solve this problem.

this is the error i'm getting:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
python3-click python3-colorama
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
libatk-bridge2.0-dev libatspi2.0-dev libdbus-1-dev libepoxy-dev libgtk-3-dev
libxkbcommon-dev libxtst-dev python-gi-cairo wayland-protocols
x11proto-record-dev
Suggested packages:
libgtk-3-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
 libatk-bridge2.0-dev libatspi2.0-dev libdbus-1-dev libepoxy-dev libgtk-3-dev
 libxkbcommon-dev libxtst-dev python-gi-cairo ros-melodic-smach-viewer
 wayland-protocols x11proto-record-dev
 0 upgraded, 11 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
 Need to get 83.6 kB/1,551 kB of archives.
 After this operation, 16.1 MB of additional disk space will be used.
 Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
 Err:1 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 ros-melodic-smach-viewer amd64 3.                                             0.0-1bionic.20210414.224955
 404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.233.100 80]
 E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-melodic-smach-viewer/ros-melodic-smach-viewer_3.0.0-1bionic.20210414.224955_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.233.100 80]
 E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/378624/can%27t-install-smach_viewer-on-ros-melodic/) by [K3da](https://answers.ros.org/users/68110/k3da/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-05-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you run `sudo apt-get update` before trying to install them?

It looks like your local `apt` index is out-of-date.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-05-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [K3da](https://answers.ros.org/users/68110/k3da/) on 2021-05-21**:
This works thank you!!!. But now i have a new issue. when i run `rosrun smach_viewer simple_fsm.py`  i get an error it says `[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named simple_fsm.py below /opt/ros/melodic/share/smach_viewer` even though i have sourced my workspace and it is in my $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH thank you

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-05-21**:
Let's not conflate issues.

ROS Answers works best with a 1-to-1 ratio of questions-to-answers. Follow-up questions in comments have very little visibility, so it's better to post a new question.

**Comment by [K3da](https://answers.ros.org/users/68110/k3da/) on 2021-05-21**:
thank you so much i would do that right now.